# How to reach element with this keyword in children parameter methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object like this

```
function myObject(){
    this.$domElement = $('#apple');
    this.name = 'apple';
    this.color = 'green';
    this.price = '200';

    this.show = function(){
       this.$domElement.show()
    }
}
```

Now I want to add a new method to this object like this

```
this.setCss = {
    position : function(){
        //...
    },

    opacity : function(){
        //...
    },

    border : function(){
        //...
    }
}
```

Now, my question : How can I reach my object again with `this` keyword.

The final code I am expecting is something like this. If possible...

```
function myObject(){
    this.$domElement = $('#apple');
    this.name = 'apple';
    this.color = 'green';
    this.price = '200';
    this.show = function(){
       this.$domElement.show()
    }
    this.setCss = {
        position : function(){
        //...this.$domElement.css({top:10,left:20})
        },
        opacity : function(){
        //...this.$domElement.css({opacity:.5})
        },
        border : function(){
        //...this.$domElement.css({border:'1px solid red'})
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried if it works?

Comment: Also, your `this.setCss` is an object, so `position = function() .. ` should be `position: function() ..`.

Comment: Yes, right, it was only a sample, let me correct it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
 function myObject(){
   //init
   var me = this;

    this.$domElement = $('#apple');
    this.name = 'apple';
    this.color = 'green';
    this.price = '200';

    this.show = function(){
       //use
       me.$domElement.show()
    }
}

var obj = new myObject();
obj.show();
```

Comment: Might be better to use `_this` instead of `me` tho. Less confusing.

Comment: It's just personal preference using `_this`, `that` or `me`.